# How do I tag my CSS file with a version number that jQuery can read?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a Javascript library that comes with a CSS file. I would like for the JS to check the CSS file version.

My best idea is CSS like this

```
body { someproperty: "v1.3.1"; }
```

and then you can have JS code like this

```
console.log($("body").css("someproperty"))
```

But I'm having a hard time finding the perfect property. Is there some semi obsolete one that takes an arbitrary string or number?

Any other ideas?

---

@Niet the Dark Absolless gave the perfect answer to my question, but I ended up handling my CSS purely in JS:

```
$('head').append(my_css)
```

This gives me one single file to distribute, which can never get out of sync with itself. Good Times!

Comment: The usual way to do that would be to add it to the filename, not in a invalid style ?

Comment: i agree css is probably not the place to do this.  put it in the filename or in a javascript variable somewhere.

Comment: I mean, you can use a very specific `class`, specify a valid property (and the value containing the version somehow). Then, in jQuery, you can create an element, add the `class`, and get the property's value. This way, you don't have to affect your live DOM in any way (unless you try to use the `class`, which you obviously wouldn't want to do)

Comment: I can't ask my users to change the css file name on every HTML page each time I release a new version.

Comment: How about if your JS pulls in the CSS file, so users don't have to include the CSS file name at all?

Comment: @andi, that would be even better! How does one do that?

Comment: Take a look at this page for some info and demo: http://otaqui.com/blog/1263/simple-script-to-load-css-from-javascript/

Comment: Nice! I ended up doing $('head').append(my_css) instead. Now I have a single single self contained file to distribute, and nothing can ever get out of sync!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is. Sort of.

```
body {content:"Hello, world!";}
```

Because it's not a psuedo-elment, it has no effect.

But if you then do:

```
console.log($("body").css("content"));
```

... [Close enough!](http://jsfiddle.net/C2ewP/) -- Just need to strip the quotes from the start and end ;)

```
console.log($("body").css("content").slice(1,-1));
```

Comment: `.replace(/^['"]|['"]$/g, '')` should do.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Or just `.slice(1,-1)`

Comment: Well thought out! `:D`

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript file which defines the version and then load the stylesheet via javascript.  Include the javascript file instead of the CSS file:

```
function getVersion()
{
    return '1.0';
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css"/>');
});
```